# Cannot echo individual values of an object in Joomla 3.2

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.2

following this tutorial here: http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Selecting_Records_from_a_Single_Table

I have created a function as follows:

```
function getItemForBid() {
        // Get a db connection.
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        // Create a new query object.
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Select item record matching the $orderID
        $query
            ->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'created_by', 'itemtitle', 'deliverydestination', 'listprice')))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__entrusters_items'))
            ->where('id = '.$_GET['orderID']);           
        // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
        $db->setQuery($query);

        // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$db->setQuery($query);
$bidItem = $db->loadObject();
//print_r($bidItem);
}
```

The `print_r($bidItem);` works and returns e.g.:

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 4 
    [created_by] => 216 
    [itemtitle] => Tennis Racket 
    [deliverydestination] => London 
    [listprice] => 5000 
)
```

however if I try to echo one of the values elsewhere on the page i.e. like this:

```
<input name="jform[item_id]" id="jform_item_id" value="<?php echo $bidItem->id; ?> " readonly="" type="text">
```

I get nothing. The manual says you can access the individual values by using:

```
$result->index // e.g. $result->email
```

Am I doing something very stupid?

Comment: Don#t use `$_GET` with Joomla. Please refer to the documentation for getting input values: http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Comment: [itemtitle] => Large Black Dildo

Comment: @Loïc That's embarrassing! The db entry was by the client, who has a strange sense of humour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$bidItem is local to the function you created. Declare it as global to use it elsewhere on the page. Modify the last lines of your function like:

```
    global $bidItem;
    $bidItem = $db->loadObject();
}
```

Then before you use it in your HTML add:

```
<?php global $bidItem; ?>
```

Comment: No, $this->bidItem = $db->loadObject();  Or just return it, it really is hard to know what you are doing when you are not showing the return statement.

Comment: Using `global`s seriously?

Comment: The user didn't explain what they were trying to do. They've clearly run their function at some point but their question doesn't show where so my answer is the simplest possible based on the details provided.

Comment: Sorry - my fault. Beginner. The entire file is visible here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1cw-hak  VERY grateful for suggestions of how to replace the $_GET and avoid using globals, if that is not not recommended

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `$_GET` with Joomla, you should use JInput like so:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$orderID = $jinput->get('orderID', null, null);
```

As for you database query, try changing `loadObject();` to `loadObjectList();`

Then also don't forget to change this:

```
->where('id = '.$_GET['orderID']);
```

to this:

```
->where('id = '. $orderID);
```

Comment: That results in a mysql error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 SQL=SELECT `id`,`created_by`,`itemtitle`,`deliverydestination`,`listprice` FROM `mous_entrusters_items` WHERE id =

Comment: Mmm odd, stick with @nathans answer but still dont use `$_GET`

Comment: My answer was only to fix the issue they were describing so there may be other issues with the code that I didn't cover. Fixing the use of $_GET is a good idea. At the very least it should be checked to make sure it's set and is an integer.