# Joomla 3.2 function returning no data

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

Grateful if you can help me understand why this function is not returning anything.

This is the function, following the Joomla tutorial.

```
function relatedBids() {
        // Get a db connection.
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        // Create a new query object.
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Select item record matching the $orderID
        $query
            ->select('*')
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__entrusters_bids'))
            ->where('item_id = '.$_GET['orderID']);          
        // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.

        // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
        $db->setQuery($query);
        global $itemBids;
        $itemBids = $db->loadObject();
        //print_r($itemBids);
}
// if you want to call the function on some button click

relatedBids();
```

Here is how I am trying to load the results:

```
      <ul>
        <?php global $itemBids; ?>
        <?php foreach ($itemBids as $itemBid) :?>
        <li><?php echo $itemBid->created.''.$itemBid->bid; ?></li>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the problem

```
->where('item_id = '.$_GET['orderID']);
```

First what are you getting for `$_GET['orderID']` and why in the wold are you doing a GET like that inside of Joomla?

Second, if it isn't a field name you need to use `$db->quote($_GET['orderID'])`.

And why are you using globals, even though that's unrelated? Why are you not just returning the results or using `$this->itemBids`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. please see the advice I was given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102813/cannot-echo-individual-values-of-an-object-in-joomla-3-2/22102932?noredirect=1#comment33529468_22102932   which explains why I am using globals and why Jinput doesn't seem to work in this case. orderID is passed in the URL. It belongs to a different table, again if there is a better way please let me know.

Comment: This is the file I am trying to get working: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1cw-hak

Comment: JInput gets all the data from the url and sanitizes it correctly. What table the data comes from make no difference to your url. Your basic problem is not having tick marks. You never need to use globals like that. I don't see anything in that post that justifies using a global Break up the method if you can't return what you need.

Comment: Ok I started to fix that but what in the world are you doing with database queries and html in the same file? And what class are you in? Is this inside a view class? What is $this when this code is running?

Comment: Yes this is in a view. The component is generated by joomla component creator. As I have been experimenting with various db structure changes in component creator I wanted an easy way to generate a new version without losing my work on the views. So this view is an override of an edit item view the component creator makes. I assumed I can only override views in templates/mytemplate/html/ so I added the additional queries i needed in there (at least temporarily). Is there a better way?

Comment: This is completely wrong. You shoudl look at com_weblinks or com_content and structure your component like that.  You should never ever have queries in a layout file, that should only be html.  You should put those queries where they belong ... this cannot work and this is why you are having problems, you do not have a class.  Put your queries into the model where they belong you will not waste time solving problems that do not exist when you do things correctly.

Comment: Thanks - will do that. So I am guessing I should move these two functions from the views/bidform/tmpl/default.php to models/bidform.php right?